# How to prevent cell table data to wrap in this case?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

In this captured image :

[image]

The code of the page is :

```
<div align="center">
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width='98%' class="formulaire">
    <tr>
        <td width="5%"><img style="cursor:pointer"  id="img_rech"  width="16px" border="0" title="<?php echo _getText('main.recherche') ?>"  src="<?php echo HTTP_ICONES ?>ic_zoom.png" onclick="afficherRech()"></td>
        <td width="75%" class="normaltext" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" id="nb_total" value="<?php echo $data['event']['cnt']; ?>" />
            <span id="nb_enreg"></span><span id="total_enreg"><?php echo $data['event']['cnt'] . " " . _getText('main.accueil.evenement'); ?></span>
        </td>
        <td class="normaltext" width="10%" align="right"><span id="labelFiltre"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.filtre'); ?></span></td>
        <td width="10%" align="right">
        <select id="filtreList" name="filtreList" onchange="filtrerList(this.value)" class="selectnormalCourt">
            <option value="-1"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.filtre.tous'); ?></option>
            <option value="05">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The JQuery of the listbox event is :

```
<script language="javascript">
    function filtrerList(nb_rows)
    {
        var nb_total = $('#nb_total').val();
        var num = new Number(nb_rows); // pour ne pas afficher le "0" avant le chiffre ( 05 )
        nb_total = new Number(nb_total);
        if (num != -1)
        {
            if (nb_rows > nb_total)
            {
                $('#nb_enreg').html(nb_total + ' sur ');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#nb_enreg').html(num + ' sur ');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $('#nb_enreg').html('');
        }

        var html = $.ajax({
            data: "nb_rows="+nb_rows+"&mp="+<?php echo $_SESSION[MANUEL]; ?> ,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX_REF ?>ReferentielFiltrerListEventsAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;
        $('#list').html(html);
    }
</script>
```

How to remove the line-break which I encircled in red ?

Here are CSS :

```
.formulaire {
    border: 0px solid;
    border-color:#b80500;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.normaltext{
    width:150px;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}

.formulaire .selectnormalCourt {
    width: 63px;
    background-color:#FFFF; 
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#b80500;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #000;
    background-position: 10px 6px;
    float: right;
}

.formulaire .selectnormalCourt:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #699DE3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
    color: #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear from the code posted how the text is generated, but you should simply identify which element will contain the text “5 sur 13 événements”, or something like that, and set `white-space: nowrap` on it in CSS. If this breaks the layout, redesign the layout to accommodate the text.

Comment: In the text "5 sur 13 événements" : "5 sur 13" is written into the first `span` element and the "13 événement" is in the second `span` element.

Comment: @Pheromix, then an extra `span` element around them is needed.

Comment: I wrote this : `<span style="white-space:nowrap"><span id="nb_enreg"></span><span id="total_enreg"><?php echo $data['event']['cnt'] . " " . _getText('main.accueil.evenement'); ?></span></span>` but the line-break didn't disappear !

Comment: @Pheromix, I think you need to post sample code, consisting of actual HTML and CSS code (as opposite to PHP code that generates HTML). Alternatively, a URL might be useful.